# Android cannot set default button style

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I am trying to set a default background for all buttons in my application. The problem is the `android:buttonStyle` item does not seam to do anything.

If I set a style of `@style/Button` to any button, then the style is used but I want this to happen to *all* buttons that have no style explicitly supplied.

My `themes.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style
        name="BBTheme"
        parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_background</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and my `styles.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style
        name="ActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

        <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_background</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Button styles -->
    <style
        name="Button"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">

        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: same problem...any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Add the buttonstyles.xml inside your drawable folder call From Button, you can modify the style of button.

```
<Button
                            android:id="@+id/button6"
                            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="140dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyles"
                            android:text="Cancel"
                            android:textColor="#fff" />
```

buttonstyles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#99d9fa"
        android:endColor="#99d9fa"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="3dp"
        android:top="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:bottom="3dp" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: As I specified in my question, I don't want to have to set the style each time I use a `Button`, I want to set a default style for all buttons.

Comment: check this link , it may useful for you-http://www.androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=3307

Comment: I went through that and its exactly what I am doing, but with no results. I am extending `Widget.Button` in my style and setting a background image but that image never is displayed unless I set that style directly to the `Button` - not by default like I want.